# How to get random Element from CollectionType?

Tags: swift2

This is my example code

```
import Foundation // ar4random_uniform

extension CollectionType where Self.Index.Distance == Int {
    var randomElement: Self.Generator.Element? {
        if !isEmpty {
            let i = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count)))
            return self[startIndex.advancedBy(i)]
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}

let arr = ["alfa", "beta","gama"]
let view = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".characters
let dict:Dictionary<Int,Any> = [1:"a",2:true,3:1]
let range = Range<Int>(start: -99, end: 100)
let b = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.alloc(10)
for i in 0..<10 { (b+i).memory = 1000*i }
let buff = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Int>(start: b, count: 10)
for i in 0...10 {
    print(arr.randomElement!,
        view.randomElement!,
        dict.randomElement!,
        range.randomElement!,
        buff.randomElement!)
}

/*
gama z (1, "a") 62 2000
alfa i (1, "a") 4 9000
alfa f (1, "a") 14 6000
gama g (1, "a") 68 8000
beta a (2, true) 42 7000
alfa y (1, "a") -76 1000
alfa i (1, "a") 76 4000
gama f (2, true) 79 3000
beta s (2, true) 46 3000
beta l (1, "a") -17 9000
gama q (3, 1) 62 9000
*/
```

The code works as expected.

Question is, which Swift's build-in type conforms to CollectionType protocol where `Self.Index.Distance != Int` and how to implement the same behaviour in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
typealias Distance : _SignedIntegerType = Int
```

So every `Index.Distance` must conform to `_SignedIntegerType`. Every `_SignedIntegerType` promises conversion to and from `IntMax` (the widest available integer):

```
init(_: IntMax)
func toIntMax() -> IntMax
```

Put these two facts together, and we can compute a random index (up to 2<sup>31</sup>-1 elements; this will crash for collections larger than that):

```
let randomDistance = Index.Distance(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count.toIntMax())).toIntMax())
let randomIndex = startIndex.advancedBy(randomDistance)
return self[randomIndex]
```

Comment: thank you Rob! i have explored the same, that is why i can not understand, why i have trouble to write this simple extension without specifying 'where Self.Index.Distance == Int'.